# Serialize List in a WebService to Json and pass to ajax on load

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, web-services

I am trying to pass a list that is populated by the database in a Web Service to ajax using JSON. However, I'm not sure what I'm missing and where to go from here.

> Web Service

```
public class RetrieveWidgets : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static RetrieveWidgetsDAL[] GetWidgets()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dboCao"].ConnectionString);

        List<RetrieveWidgetsDAL> GetWidgetList = new List<RetrieveWidgetsDAL>();

        int getUserId;
        string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmdGetUserId = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserId FROM tUser WHERE UserName = @UserName", conn))
        {
            cmdGetUserId.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);
            getUserId = Convert.ToInt32(cmdGetUserId.ExecuteScalar());

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(" --------------- " + getUserId + " --------------- " + userName + " ---------");
        }

        using (SqlCommand cmdGetWidgets = new SqlCommand("SELECT Title, SortNo, Collapsed, ColumnId FROM tWidgets WHERE UserId = @UserId", conn))
        {
            cmdGetWidgets.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", getUserId);

            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmdGetWidgets.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    RetrieveWidgetsDAL widgetDAL = new RetrieveWidgetsDAL();
                    widgetDAL.Title = rdr.GetString(0);
                    widgetDAL.SortNo = rdr.GetInt32(1);
                    widgetDAL.Collapsed = rdr.GetInt32(2);
                    widgetDAL.ColumnId = rdr.GetInt32(3);
                    GetWidgetList.Add(widgetDAL);
                }
            }

            //trying to serialize GetWidgetList to JSON
            var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var strJSON = js.Serialize(GetWidgetList);// not sure if this is the correct way?

        }
        conn.Close();

        return GetWidgetList.ToArray();
    }
}
```

> Data Structure class

```
public class RetrieveWidgetsDAL
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortNo { get; set; }
    public int Collapsed { get; set; }
    public int ColumnId { get; set; }
}
```

> ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null) {
            $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
            $('#popup').dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8",
                url: "Webservices/RetrieveWidgets.asmx/GetWidgets",
                data: <---don't know how to get the data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(data);
            }
            });
        }
    });
```

I'm new to the idea of JSON so I'm still struggling to learn it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is what I receive now on error in the browser console..

[image]

EDIT 2: I've removed static from my webservice..

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<RetrieveWidgetsDAL> GetWidgets()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dboCao"].ConnectionString);
        List<RetrieveWidgetsDAL> lstData = new List<RetrieveWidgetsDAL>();
        int getUserId;
        string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmdGetUserId = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserId FROM tUser WHERE UserName = @UserName", conn))
        {
            cmdGetUserId.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);
            getUserId = Convert.ToInt32(cmdGetUserId.ExecuteScalar());

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(" --------------- " + getUserId + " --------------- " + userName + " ---------");
        }

        using (SqlCommand cmdGetWidgets = new SqlCommand("SELECT Title, SortNo, Collapsed, ColumnId FROM tWidgets WHERE UserId = @UserId", conn))
        {
            cmdGetWidgets.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", getUserId);
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmdGetWidgets.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    RetrieveWidgetsDAL widgetDAL = new RetrieveWidgetsDAL();
                    widgetDAL.Title = rdr.GetString(0);
                    widgetDAL.SortNo = rdr.GetInt32(1);
                    widgetDAL.Collapsed = rdr.GetInt32(2);
                    widgetDAL.ColumnId = rdr.GetInt32(3);
                    lstData.Add(widgetDAL);
                }
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
        return lstData;
    }
```

Now my console shows [object Object]

[image]

Edit 3: I used the solution that has the accepted answer, however.. had to fix the ajax..

contentType was missing a ;

> contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

and now it alerts on the success!

Comment: `data` set in `$.ajax(` is used to send data to your URL (in this case, webservice). You get your data from `.done(function( data ) {`. This is the data sent by your webserver to your jquery/javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<RetrieveWidgetsDAL> GetWidgets()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dboCao"].ConnectionString);
    List<RetrieveWidgetsDAL> lstData= new List<RetrieveWidgetsDAL>();
    int getUserId;
    string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmdGetUserId = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserId FROM tUser WHERE UserName = @UserName", conn))
            {
                cmdGetUserId.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);
                getUserId = Convert.ToInt32(cmdGetUserId.ExecuteScalar());
    
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(" --------------- " + getUserId + " --------------- " + userName + " ---------");
            }
    
            using (SqlCommand cmdGetWidgets = new SqlCommand("SELECT Title, SortNo, Collapsed, ColumnId FROM tWidgets WHERE UserId = @UserId", conn))
            {
                cmdGetWidgets.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", getUserId);
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmdGetWidgets.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        RetrieveWidgetsDAL widgetDAL = new RetrieveWidgetsDAL();
                        widgetDAL.Title = rdr.GetString(0);
                        widgetDAL.SortNo = rdr.GetInt32(1);
                        widgetDAL.Collapsed = rdr.GetInt32(2);
                        widgetDAL.ColumnId = rdr.GetInt32(3);
                        lstData.Add(widgetDAL);
                    }
                }
           }
            conn.Close();
           return lstData;
        }
    }
```

**JS:** On success use `response.d`

```
          $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8",
                url: "Webservices/RetrieveWidgets.asmx/GetWidgets",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);  // try using response.d
                },
                error:function (repo){
                      console.log(repo);
                }
            });
```

Comment: I'm getting an error at public static list<RetrieveWidgetsDAL> GetWidgets().. Error 13 The type or namespace name 'list' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think you need to import namespace by adding `using System.Collections.Generic;`  http://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Comment: typo error make L in caps `List<RetrieveWidgetsDAL>`

Comment: Yep, I just noticed that too. Haha. However, I'm still not getting an alert on success. I'm checking the console but I don't see any errors, just warnings. Actually, I'll update my question with the console information.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to change your webserver return:

```
public class RetrieveWidgets : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static RetrieveWidgetsDAL[] GetWidgets()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then change your jquery:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8",
            url: "Webservices/RetrieveWidgets.asmx/GetWidgets",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json"
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            alert(data);
        });
```

Comment: what is this line doing exactly?  
$("#results").append(html);

Comment: Basically, your data is sent to this function: `done`. You can use how you want in your javascript/jquery.

Comment: Ah, okay, so if I'm not getting an alert, the data isn't getting passed? I'm not receiving an alert.

Comment: If you access from your browser your changed webservice, what is the return?

Comment: When I debug my error function shows. So that's indicating that it's not working? It's not returning anything.